# Filter the score of the questions on the homepage before loading them

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, homepage

At the moment questions on the homepage are loaded by the top N most recent and then ones with a score of -4 or less are filtered out. This doesn't make much difference for a user who is logged in but consider anonymous users; their home page is only 15 questions in length. If someone was to edit several posts that bump to the top with a score of -4 or less then the home page looks tiny.

At the moment on SFF, for example, the homepage for anonymous users only shows 9 questions:

[image: Screenshot of the homepage of SFF as seen by anonymous users]

At one point it only showed 3 questions (a few weeks back):

[image]

Can the filtering logic be changed to *before* the questions are loaded to appear on the homepage?

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion. Just a heads up that this is in our list to revisit. When we come back to this, we'll have more on this post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You were almost spot-on on the issue here, with one caveat: there were a couple of missing filters on the backend in relation to our frontend filtering, however the backend data for homepage questions is cached, which means that it could take a long time for recent changes to a post to reflect on the homepage.

Unfortunately we can't remove that cache, and re-architecting it to a proper event-based solution is currently out of the question.

However we went ahead and added the missing filters in the backend, and made it so a buffer of extra questions is cached whenever that cache is created, which should strongly mitigate the issue of a low number of questions being displayed in the homepage.

Thank you for reporting this issue, appreciate the help!